# How do I set ECK cluster's PV to be an existing file share in my azure storage account?

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes

I am a beginner in ECK and Azure services in general, so would appreciate some help in setting up.

I am trying to setup elastic and kibana clusters, and setting the PV as an existing file share on my azure storage account.

However, after looking through the tutorials, I can't figure it out.

these are the PV and elastic cluster yaml files:

pv-storage.yaml:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: elastic-storage2
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 10Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  mountOptions:
    - dir_mode=0755
    - file_mode=0755
  # storageClassName: storage-azure
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Retain
  azureFile:
    secretName: azure-secret
    shareName: elasticsearchfile2
    readOnly: false
```

elastic-cluster.yaml

```
apiVersion: elasticsearch.k8s.elastic.co/v1 
kind: Elasticsearch 
metadata: 
  name: quickstart
spec: 
  version: 7.11.1 #Make sure you use the version of your choice 
  http: 
    service: 
      spec: 
        type: LoadBalancer #Adds a External IP 
  nodeSets: 
  - name: default 
    count: 1 
    config: 
      node.master: true 
      node.data: true 
      node.ingest: true 
      node.store.allow_mmap: false 
    volumeClaimTemplates:
    - metadata:
        name: elasticsearch-data
        annotations:
          volume.beta.kubernetes.io/storage-class: ""
      spec:
        accessModes:
        - ReadWriteMany
        resources:
          requests:
            storage: 1Gi
        volumeName: elastic-storage2
```

error messages from describing the elastic pod:

```
Events:
  Type     Reason     Age                   From               Message
  ----     ------     ----                  ----               -------
  Normal   Scheduled  17m                   default-scheduler  Successfully assigned default/quickstart-es-default-0 to aks-agentpool-23635388-vmss000001
  Normal   Pulled     17m                   kubelet            Container image "docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.11.1" already present on machine
  Normal   Created    17m                   kubelet            Created container elastic-internal-init-filesystem
  Normal   Started    17m                   kubelet            Started container elastic-internal-init-filesystem
  Warning  Unhealthy  16m                   kubelet            Readiness probe failed: {"timestamp": "2021-02-25T04:27:10+00:00", "message": "readiness probe failed", "curl_rc": "7"}
  Normal   Started    15m (x4 over 17m)     kubelet            Started container elasticsearch
  Warning  Unhealthy  15m                   kubelet            Readiness probe failed: OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: container_linux.go:370: starting container process caused: process_linux.go:103: executing setns process caused: exit status 1: unknown
  Normal   Pulled     15m (x5 over 17m)     kubelet            Container image "docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.11.1" already present on machine
  Normal   Created    15m (x5 over 17m)     kubelet            Created container elasticsearch
  Warning  BackOff    2m13s (x62 over 16m)  kubelet            Back-off restarting failed container
```

Error logs from the elastic pod:

```
{"type": "deprecation", "timestamp": "2021-02-25T07:53:03,175Z", "level": "DEPRECATION", "component": "o.e.d.c.s.Settings", "cluster.name": "quickstart", "node.name": "quickstart-es-default-0", "message": "[node.data] setting was deprecated in Elasticsearch and will be removed in a future release! See the breaking changes documentation for the next major version." }
{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2021-02-25T07:53:03,596Z", "level": "ERROR", "component": "o.e.b.ElasticsearchUncaughtExceptionHandler", "cluster.name": "quickstart", "node.name": "quickstart-es-default-0", "message": "uncaught exception in thread [main]", 
"stacktrace": ["org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.StartupException: ElasticsearchException[failed to bind service]; nested: AccessDeniedException[/usr/share/elasticsearch/data/nodes];",
```

Thanks in advance and let me know if you need any more details.

Comment: please share the tutorial link you are following and looks like you are using the CRD to setup and manage the Elasticsearch cluster.

Comment: I'm mostly folliwng this tutorial, while putting the pvc section into the volumeClaimTemplates section in my elastic cluster deployment file.https://medium.com/dataseries/creating-persistent-volume-in-azure-kubernetes-service-aks-using-azure-files-2a48d4e08fb8

Comment: I also see a lot of different approaches, like defining storage classes, or different mounting options, but not sure which ones are necessary.

Comment: you can simply create the PVC and use it with deployment of Elasticsearch however if you want to use specific type of SSD or disk you can create the storage class also. If storage class not there it will consider the default one as the default storage class.

Comment: you are doing but i have question the tutorial you are following is using the azure storage or files system not HDD or SDD will be okay with Elasticsearch when writing the snapshot to file system?

Comment: with inital logs looks like you readiness is failing or please check the logs of your ES or contianer not getting killed OOM.

Comment: Thanks for your replies! I don't have preferences for what disk to use, I just want the PV to be mounted on the azure storage account I have. Do you mean that elasticsearch is incompatible with azure file share?